# how to run a function to a specific selector of a class within document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a fade out function happen in javascript when you click on a specific class, but I am having a hard time trying to get a specific class to fade out. I was trying to use the **this** keyword, but I guess I'm using it wrong because it keeps saying that it is not defined.

```
<div class="opaque">
<h3>Fade Heading</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
</div>

<div class="opaque">
<h3>Fade Heading</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
</div>

<div class="opaque">
<h3>Fade Heading</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
</div>

 var o =1;
 var r = 0.1;
 var a;
 var counter;
 var e;


 function myFunction(e)
{
 e = this.style.opacity = o;
console.log(this.style.opacity);
counter = setInterval(fadeO(e),5000);



}

function execute()
{  


  a = document.getElementsByClassName('opaque');
  for( var i = 0; i< a.length; i++)
  {
    a[i].addEventListener('click',myFunction(e));
  }

}//end execute

function fadeO(e)
{
 this.a = document.getElementsByClassName('opaque');


if(e.style.opacity <=0)
{
 clearInterval(counter);
}
else{
 e.style.opacity = o ;
 console.log(e.style.opacity);
  o -=0.1;

}
}

window.onload = function()
{

execute();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems here, in both `addEventListener` and `setInterval()` you are invoking the handler directly instead of passing the function referneces.

```js
var o = 1;
var r = 0.1;
var a;
var counter;
var e;


function myFunction(e) {
  this.style.opacity = 1;
  console.log(this.style.opacity);
  counter = setInterval(fadeO.bind(this), 100);//again need to pass a function reference to `interval()` don't invoke the function by adding (), in this solution instead of passing the element reference as an argument we are passing it as the `this` reference by using Function.bind()
}

function execute() {
  a = document.getElementsByClassName('opaque');
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);//pass the handler reference, don't invoke it by adding `()`
  }

} //end execute

function fadeO() {
  if (this.style.opacity <= 0) {
    clearInterval(counter);
  } else {
    this.style.opacity = o;
    console.log(this.style.opacity);
    o -= 0.1;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  execute();
}
```

```html
<div class="opaque">
  <h3>Fade Heading</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
</div>

<div class="opaque">
  <h3>Fade Heading</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
</div>

<div class="opaque">
  <h3>Fade Heading</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo.</p>
</div>
```

<sub>Note: This solution will need further changes to support multiple clicks and so on</sub>

Answer (score 0):

What is `e` from

```
 for( var i = 0; i< a.length; i++)
  {
    a[i].addEventListener('click',myFunction(e));
  }
```

Try

```
for( var i = 0; i< a.length; i++)
  {
    a[i].addEventListener('click',myFunction, false);
  }
```

See [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) .`This` meaning always depend on how your function is called. In your case . Your this if called right should have the value of your `e`.  Check here [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)